# Android room does not trigger when child table is changed on join query

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-room

Imagine we have one to many relationship.
Two tables, one is **parent_table** and another is **child_table**.
Two entity classes called **ParentEntity** and **ChildEntity**.
And one embeded class called **ParentWithChild** using it on join query result.

**ParentEntity** Class

```
@Entity(tableName = "parent_table")
data class ChildEntity(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id")
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        val id: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_name")
        val name: String,
)
```

**ChildEntity** Class

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "child_table",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ParentEntity::class,
        parentColumns = ["parent_id"],
        childColumns = ["parent_owner_id"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        deferred = false
    )])
data class ChildEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "child_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_owner_id")
    val childId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "child_name")
    val name: String,
)
```

**ParentWithChild** Class

```
data class ParentWithChild(
    @Embedded
    val parent: ParentEntity?,
    @Embedded
    val child : ChildEntity?,
)
```

And the sample query in **dao** class is

```
@Query("""
       select * 
       from parent_table left join child_table on parent_table.parent_id = child_table.parent_owner_id 
    """)
abstract fun loadParentsWithChildren(): Flow<List<ParentWithChild>>
```

Now two scenarios come to play, if we use **loadParentsWithChildren()** mehtod.

1- If parent table is updated the trigger happens and the new data stream emitted by room.

2- **If the child table is updated the room does not re fetch the join query statements.**

My problem is the second scenario, what am I doing wrong ?

- Using Room Stable Release 2.2.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question has some inconsistencies. Notably, some places you refer to `ParentWithChild` and other places you have `ChildWithDeviceEntity`. But, assuming that is just editing errors in the question, it does not appear that you are doing anything wrong. Make sure that you are on the latest version of Room. If the problem persists, create a sample project that demonstrates the problem, then file an issue. It is possible that the Room invalidation tracker is not correctly handling `left join`.

Comment: Hi, thx for commenting.
Even the single join does not work at all or using @Relation annotation.
Note that if parent table is updated, everything works, but my problem is when child table is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding **enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()** when creating room database, my problem solved.

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room
            .databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "app.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
            .build()
    }

}
```

But still I wonder that how I'm using different database instance since I'm using Hilt library and following singletone pattern, and I'm also not using database in multi process ...

Comment: "But still I wonder that how I'm using different database instance since I'm using Hilt library and following singletone pattern, and I'm also not using database in multi process ..." Add `@Singleton` on your provide function as by default it's unscoped.